# Vista Message Box issue

Tags: windows-vista

I have a custom application running on an unattended Windows Vista box. This application run various SQL commands and does standard maintenance.

Whenever a message box is displayed, it "freezes" the application causing major issues. A simple click of the OK button clears the message box and the application continues on it's own.

Is there a registry hack or some other type of fix that I can implement that either disables the message box or automatically closes it?

Answer (score 1):

You could look into some of the windows scripting tools that can script the mouse click for you.

Something like this maybe: http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml

Comment: Or [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). It includes a recorder as well as a tool for associating any window with its source.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the only "solution" is to gain access to the source code of the application and change the code. The behaviour is prevalent in apps which use a single thread for all tasks. When there is a single thread, which is busy processing the request, any other tasks (including UI updates) will take a back seat and will not get processed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

This message box isn't coming from the application, but from Vista itself. The computer contains a special PCI card that is working just fine, but Visa for some reason doesn't think so. 

That's the reason I want to disable the message box.

Thanks.

Comment: UPDATE: The vendor updated the client software so the error box no longer appears. Thanks to everyone for you help.

Comment: Good to hear @Richard.